# Whats wrong with this code DirectX

Tags: directx

I am coding DirectX. I made a new project for directx 11,Although my coding book is for directx 6.0 and is how to code a real time strategy game, and is written in 1999.I have some errors here is my code and and my errors

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code

```
//*********************************8***********************************************************************************************************************

//win main

#include <windows.h>
#include "pch.h"
#define wc 
#define WNDCLASS
#define RegisterClass
#define CreateWindowEx

LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************************/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCdLine, int)
{
    MSG       msg;
    HWND      WindowHandle;
    WNDCLASS  wc;
    char  ClassName[] = "Basic Windows";

    hPrevInstance = hPrevInstance;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;




    wc.cdWndExtra = 0;

    wc.hInstant = hInstance;

    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;


    wc.lpszMenuName = ClassName;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;


    RegisterClass (&wc);

    WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        ClassName,
        ClassName,
        WS_POPUP,
        0,
        0,
        640,
        480
        NULL,
        Null,
        hInstance
        NULL);










}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with this code

Comment: where are the errors?  what version of studio?  did you create this as a c++ project?  Which project template did you use?

Comment: The template was Direct X on vs 2015.

Comment: the errors are on the wc then there is an error with the dot then there are errors with the 1st NULL in 
    WindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        ClassName,
        ClassName,
        WS_POPUP,
        0,
        0,
        640,
        480
        NULL,
        Null,
        hInstance
        NULL);
and the equal sigh there

Comment: And the ) in  RegisterClass (&wc);

Comment: I suggest you install this [VSIX](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/raw/master/VSIX/Direct3DUWPGame.vsix) and use one of the Direct3D Game templates it provides as a starting point. It will set up a window, device, and swapchain. See the DirectX Tool Kit [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for a more detailed explanation of the template.

Comment: You should essentially ignore the DirectX API information in a book on DirectX 6. So much has changed since the that it's probably more confusing that helpful to use it as a reference. That said, the general concepts around how to build an RTS are likely still applicable. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx) for some DirectX 11 book suggestions & notes.

Comment: How about for the actual game coding.Not the introduction.like How you code for troops, and the main village.

Comment: This is the book i am using https://books.google.com/books?id=8pjgAAAAMAAJ&dq=how+to+code+a+rts+game&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=